# Can Chef detect unused Cookbooks?

Tags: chef-infra

Can Chef detect if some Cookbooks in my repository are unused?

Can it detect unused Cookbooks just for a single recipe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chef can't really tell by itself, but you can use `knife search node` to gather up the expanded run list (stored in the "recipes" attribute) for each node then use regular Unix tools to clean it up.  This will give you a list of cookbook used.  Compare this with what's in your repo to determine unused cookbooks

```
$ knife search node '*:*' -a recipes | \
    grep "^ " | sort | uniq | tr -d ' '
apache2
apt
chef-client
chef-client::config
chef-client::delete_validation
...
```

Filter out every line with "::" to remove recipe and leave just cookbooks.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am currently using Chef Solo and `knife` doesn't work with it, but it is more important to know that Chef itself just doesn't have this feature (which is even more interesting on server side).

Comment: BEWARE! This does not output cookbooks which are used as a dependencies (like sudo cookbook is usually used)

Answer (score 2):

I used

```
ls /var/cache/chef/cookbooks
```

to find out the list of all cached cookbooks. This list is the list of all cookbooks the chef-client used the last time. Note that chef client removes unused cookbooks from the cache.